# D&D 5e attack of opportunity vs disadvantage

Tags: dnd-5e

As a ranged character, when in melee, I attack at disadvantage. I could move away allowing me to not have that disadvantage but that will draw an attack of opportunity. I know each situation is unique but all other thing being equal, which is better, staying put or moving?

If I choose one strategy and do it every time, which one would on average produce better results?

Comment: This question cannot be answered in a situational-independent manner of any reasonable length. There's a practically unbounded amount of tactical edge-cases and situations that might completely reverse an otherwise clear judgment for one action.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a great deal on the respective chances of hitting.  If your character has a low AC, and the target also has a low AC, staying put is better.  If you both have high ACs, then backing up would be a net benefit.  Other situations may have different answers.

Comment: not looking for situational answers. i get that under certain circumstances that one choice is better than the other. I'm asking which is better if i were to only stick to one.

Comment: The reality is that the right answer is situational.  Sorry.

Comment: I feel the advice given here is both too narrow and potentially harmful for the PC. Implying the decision can/should be made on AC alone is bad advice.

Comment: Oh, sheesh.  The OP didn't even want *that* nuanced an answer, so I didn't go into all the possible factors and scenarios for a full and complete chart of answers.  I just picked one major factor to show that there isn't just one answer for all situations.

Comment: If there is no good answer, it would be preferable to provide none than to provide bad advice.

Comment: There is no *single* good answer for *all* situations; there is a good answer for any given situation, which depends on the situation.  Which is exactly what I said.  He doesn't like that I didn't give a single answer good for every situation, and you don't like that I didn't work out *all* the answers good for *all* the possible situations.  Sorry, but you'll both have to think for yourselves a little bit.